# Changing value of dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, html

so I have a dropdownlist like this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.test, new SelectList(Model.Test, "Key", "Value"), "All tests"
```

And if I select a particular option and then close the dropdownlist and open it again, the value that I selected previously remained as the default value in the drop down list.

How do I change it back to the default - "All tests"?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please add [mcve] of your code and explain what is the problem you are facing. Also if you code javascript, MVC is not relevant here, put html-code in your question.

Comment: I'm going to say that you probably use an onchange event that does some stuff with the selected value. I think the simplest way to do this is in the onchange event, process all the stuff that needs to happen and then at the end of the onchange event when everything that needs to be done is ready you can simply change the value back to default.